# Swift TwitterKitでREST APIを使った投稿が失敗する

Tags: swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

Xcode 7.1、Swift 7.1、Fabric Twitter 1.13.1です。

FabricのTwitterKitを使い、TwitterのREST APIで「POST statuses/update」をコールしていますが、成功しません。コードは以下です。

```
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    var clientError : NSError?
    let endPoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

    let params = ["status" : "testTweet"]

    let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: endPoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if (connectionError == nil) {
            print("sucess");
        }
        else {
            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
        }
    }
```

下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Optional(Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=220 
"Request failed: forbidden (403)" 

UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error :
 Your credentials do not allow access to this resource. (code 220), 
 NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json,
 NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)})
```

Twitterアプリケーションの権限を疑い、調べてみましたが、「Read & Write」となっており正しいように見えます。
なお、GET statuses/show/:id のコールには成功しています。

もしどなたか原因に心当たりがあれば、教えていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから認証周りの問題であると考えられます。

ツイッターへのアクセスには以下の4つが必要です(質問内容から察するにおそらく既に作ってあると思います)。

1. Consumer Key
2. Consumer Key Secret
3. Access Token
4. Access Token Secret

これらの認証情報を TwitterKit に設定するためにまずは

https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/twitterkit-setup.html

に書いてある

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])
```

という部分で 1 と 2 を登録します。

この部分を AppDelegate 等に書いていますでしょうか？ 書いていなかったら書いてください。

さらに

https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html#using-existing-tokens

に書いてある `logInWithExistingAuthToken:authTokenSecret:completion:` というメソッドを使って 3 と 4 を登録します。

このメソッドの completion ブロック内でツイートするコードを書いてあげるとツイートできると思います。